# Bounty on my question expired with no answers, what more can I do?

Tags: support, bounty

I have offered a bounty on my question on SO, but I'm still not getting any answers.

What more can I do to get an answer on this community? What are the options I'm left with? Or is this the end for my question?

Comment: If you're talking about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248150/dataadapter-fill-performance-anomaly) - you need to provide more information than that. How big is your database? What is your procedure doing? And so on. Can you reproduce the behavior with a tiny database with one row in one table? As it stands there could be a million reasons why you're seeing the behaviour you are. So to answer *this* question, you need to provide [far more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248150/dataadapter-fill-performance-anomaly#comment62317867_37248150).

Comment: @Rob yes, the query came to my mind cause of that question, but the question is more in general sense not that question specific.

Comment: You can add more, higher bounties. 50 points isn't a lot, and might not get the notice of experts. You can also add more specific tags. It appears you're using ADO.NET, so you could add a tag for that, which might bring visibility by experts in that field.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan good suggestion. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options that I can think of:

1. Add another, higher bounty. If you want an answer that badly, you need to pony up a bit more of your hard-earned reputation.
2. Add tags which are specific to your question. As it was, your question had [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) and [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server), which are very generic tags. Helpful for categorization, so don't remove them, but certainly broad in scope. As your question seems to ask about [ado.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ado.net), that would be a good tag to add. Your question would then be seen by people who follow that tag (potentially 977 more people at the time of this post).

Otherwise, you can try and edit the question to include more specifics, as requested in the comments. Note that responding to clarification comments with a comment is fine, but you should be sure to update the question with those clarifications as well. Editing the question will bump the post to the first page of questions. Please do be sure to make those edits substantive, as making lots of minor edits is very much frowned upon.